# Value of $\lim_{x\to 1} \left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to solve this limit and I have changed the variable so that it's like:

$$\lim_{y\to 0}\left(\dfrac{1}{y}\right)^{\frac{1}{y}}$$

I've divided it in two parts:

- $y\to 0^+$ and I've solved it using the fact that $\dfrac{1}{y}=e^{-\frac{1}{y}\ln y}$
- $y \to 0^-$ and this is the problem.

There are negative values in the function domain... but I cannot use the same strategy because that only works for positive values of $y$. Is it possible to calculate this limit? And if not, could you tell me why?

Comment: Noninteger powers of negative numbers aren't defined (as real numbers) except in certain special cases.

Comment: @UmbertoP. yes, I know that but is that enough to justify the nonexistence of the limit?

Comment: @Concept7 Ask yourself the following question: does $\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{x}$ exist?

Comment: @Andrei I would say yes because I'm working in $\mathbb{R}$ and in that set the domain would be $[0,+\infty[$ which means it would make no sense to compute the part $x\to 0^-$. But in this case I do have negative values in the domain and that makes this weird for me...

Comment: Just make the domain $(-\infty,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the domain of the function includes $x\ge1$, unless you give an explicit rule for the powers of the negatives.

Hence $$\lim_{x\to1}\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)^{1/(1-x)}=\lim_{x\to1^-}\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)^{1/(1-x)}=\infty.$$